# Can you include before/after filters in a Rails Module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wanted to add a method to two models, so I made a module like this and included it in both models.

```
module UserReputation
  def check_something
    ...
  end
end
```

That worked fine.  I then wanted to have that method called as an :after_create on all those models.  It works if I add it manually to all the models, but I wanted to be smart and include it in the module like this:

```
module UserReputation
  after_create :check_something
  def check_something
    ...
  end
end
```

But this doesn't work.  Is there any way to accomplish this and DRY up the after_create as well?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try [self.included](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/15/mixins-in-ruby/), which is called when the module is mixed into the class `base`:

```
module UserReputation
  def self.included(base)
    base.after_create :check_something
  end
end
```

Comment: Also, just to follow up, it looks like you are missing a `def` in front of `self.included(base)`, but otherwise this works great.  Thanks!