# Can any controller method be moved outside of the class to a module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module

I have a file like this:

**app/controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   ... lots of code

   before_action :set_campaign

   ... lots of code
end
```

The class is too big, so I tried moving the line `before_action :set_campaign` outside, like this:

**app/controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   ... lots of code

   include Foomodule

   ... lots of code
end

# app/lib/foomodule.rb
module Foomodule
  before_action :set_campaign
end
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I get:

```
undefined method `before_action' for Foomodule:Module
```

Comment: `before_action` will be executing during module loading, so during this loading it doesn't have access to controllers methods yet.

Answer (score 0):

filters are a rails features that only work with a controller action, look for more  [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters)

You can see the approach explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337963/can-you-include-before-after-filters-in-a-rails-module/3338057) to see if you can hook your before/after filters around modules `included` callbacks

Its basically doing this,

```
module Foomodule
  def self.included(base)
    base.before_action :set_campaign
  end
end
```